# Difference between "before you leave" and "before you go"

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

For example if I say "we need to party hard" to a friend who is leaving the city for good, what am I supposed to add in the end: "before you go" or "before you leave"?

Answer (score 4):

> For example if I say "we need to party hard" to a friend who is leaving the city for good, what am I supposed to add in the end: "before you go" or "before you leave"?

You can use either one, since *go* can mean 'to leave' [(definition 3a)](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/Go). But if I used 'leave' I would probably say 'leave town'.

'Leave town' is more specific, but 'go' still works in this context. 'Go' can mean 'go away from a place', *ie* 'go away from this city'.